# Perl: How to pass in an input without being replaced by the substitution s/// Operator?

Tags: string, perl, command, code-injection

For example,

$test = "abc";
$test =~ s/b//g;

normally test will be ac. How do I manipulate the string "abc" so that it will go through this test and still return abc.

I am trying to do a command injection so I can't change $test =~ s/b//g; but can change the input.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: I suggest you read the traditional starting point, perle https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html starting with 'The Basics' - it covers this and many more useful things.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. You may be asking one of the following: How to perform a substitution while preserving a portion of what matched in the result, or how to match with no substitution, or how to perform a substitution such that the effects show up in a new destination variable rather than in the original target.

Comment: `pos($test) = length($test);`

Comment: What exactly _is_ the test? Whether there is a `'b'` character in `$test`?  Can you state your "test" in words?  And, what do you not want to change -- the variable `$test`, into which the string `'abc'` is read?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the /r modifier. it's a new'ish feature so older versions will not run it

```
$test = "abc";
my $str= $test =~ s/b//gr;
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers

Comment: Assuming we can't change only the string abc. How would we do this?

Comment: print "failed" unless $test =~ s/b//g ;

Comment: @user5454895 it's not really clear what you mean still. You can't change the string - it's a literal value - do you mean you want to avoid changing the variable the string is assigned to, in the case that it is equal to 'abc', but are happy to change it in other cases? Or is 'abc' simply an example and you don't want to change the string regardless of the value when testing it? What exactly are the rules in plain English?

Answer (score 0):

There is no string you can pass to `s/b//g` that will result in a string that contains a `b`.

However, if you have access to `$test` and not just it's value, you could set its `pos` such that the substitution operator won't find anything.

```
$ perl -e'
   my $test = "abc";
   pos($test) = length($test);
   $test =~ s/b//g;
   CORE::say($test);
'
ac
```